# How To Get Telegram Bot ID?

Tags: telegram-bot

Anyone Who Add In My Group, I Want To Greet Them With My Bot! But After Some Time I Want To Delete That Bot Messages Too... For That I Need Bot Chat ID. So From Where I Can Get It?? The Bot Is Created With BotFather!

Answer (score 0):

To delete messages, you only need the `chat_id` of the chat the message was sent in and the `message_id` of the message. See [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage), you don't need the user id of your bot. If you need that for some other reason, you can get the via [getMe](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getme): The return value is a [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) object that has the `id` field.

Comment: I already knew it but i want to delete bot messages from group and a bot doesn't have a chat_id.

Comment: Bots have user ids. But as I already said, the `chat_id` argument of `deleteMessage` must be the chat id of the group where the message has been sent, not the bot's user id.